# Windows server 2008 hangs with blank black screen

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2

I am using and HP DL185 G5 server with Windows Server 2008 64 Bit. The primary use of this server is SQL, but it is also running Dynamics CRM.

Every so often the server hangs and is non responsive. The screen turns black and all I can do is reboot. when I check the event viewer, there are no entries related to the hang, just messages that say the last shut down was unclean (having to do hard reboots).

With no information in the event viewer, I'm not sure where to look next. This was happening every few weeks, but now it is happening every few days. The server is under more load than it has been in the past too.

Answer (score 3):

The first item I would check is the HP Integrated Management log.  Assuming that all of the ProLiant SupportPack is installed, you can view the log by using the following url when logged on to the server:  https://127.0.0.1:2381 , and select Logs from the top menu.  If there is a hardware problem, that will appear as a yellow or red splat on the main page.

Another option is if Windows is still alive, you can enable a feature that will force the system to generate a memory dump before restarting.  You will need to have a pagefile that is the same size or larger than physical memory for this to work.  When the symptom occurs, you can press  to force a blue screen crash.

**Forcing a System Crash from the Keyboard**
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff545499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: I did not have the support pack installed, I am in the process of installing it now. I have made the registry entries to allow the force crash. I'll post back when I have some more information.